# How to parse python code and only get variables with no indentation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to extract all variables in my code that have no indentation, here is a simple example:

```
import ast
import astunparse
class AnalysisNodeVisitor(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self, nodename):
        super().__init__()
        self.nodename=nodename
        self.setVariables={}
    def visit_Assign(self,node):
        print(self.nodename,astunparse.unparse(node.targets))
        #print(ast.dump(node))

        
Analyzer=AnalysisNodeVisitor("example1")
tree=ast.parse('''\
a = 10

for i in range(10):
    b=x+i

if(x==10):
    c=36

d=20
''')
Analyzer.visit(tree)
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlQQi.png):

```
example1 a

example1 b

example1 c

example1 d
```

This example prints out all the 4 variables(a,b,c and d) and I'm wondering if there is a way to make it only print the assignments a,d since there is no indentation before their assignments?

I tried to dump the nodes and see if there is something I can use to filter out the variables but I can't find anything (for example it just outputs this : 'Assign(targets=[Name(id='a', ctx=Store())], value=Num(n=10))').

Comment: I haven't used that library, but assuming the AST is stored in some kind of dictionnary, you would only look for variable assignments in the first level and ignore any intermediary (deeper) node

Comment: Thank you, but if I try to dump the whole tree and print it, I get something like this "Module(body=[Assign(targets=[Name(id='a', ctx=Store())], value=Num(n=10)), For(target=Name(id='i', ctx=Store()), iter=Call(func=Name(id='range', ctx=Load()), args=[Num(n=10)], keywords=[]), body=[Assign(targets=[Name(id='b', ctx=Store())..etc" which doesn't seem to hold any information about levels or something similar.

Comment: Place this inside your `visit_Assign` method. `print(node.col_offset)` That should give you an idea of how you can manipulate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you just look at `tree.body`, you can find all your top-level assignment statements.

Running this code:

```
import ast
import astunparse

tree=ast.parse('''\
a = 10

for i in range(10):
    b=x+i

if(x==10):
    c=36

d=20
''')

for thing in tree.body:
    if isinstance(thing, ast.Assign):
        print(astunparse.unparse(thing.targets))
```

Produces:

```
a


d
```

Comment: That's actually very simple and makes a lot of sense yet I didn't think of, this answer and axe's answer mentioned in the comment above are what I'm looknig for. Thank you